Explicit Expression of $S_2(\zeta)$ on a general Fock State?
I would like to know the explicit expression of the two-mode squeezing operator $\hat{S}_2(\zeta)$ acting on a general Fock state $|p,q\rangle$, without including any additional operators in the expression.
$\hat{S}_2(\zeta)$ is the two-mode squeezing operator defined as:
\begin{equation}
\hat{S}_2(\zeta) = \exp\left( \zeta^* \hat{a} \hat{b} - \zeta \hat{a}^\dagger \hat{b}^\dagger\right),\\
\zeta = re^{i\theta}
\end{equation}
To provide some context, I have found two specific examples where the operator $\hat{S}_2(\zeta)$ is applied to the vacuum state $|0,0\rangle$ and the number state $|p,0\rangle$:
Example (1). Apply $\hat{S}_2(\zeta) $ to vacuum state $|0,0\rangle$:
\begin{align}
|\Psi_{0,0}\rangle= \hat{S}_2(\zeta) |0,0\rangle =  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-e^{i\theta} \tanh r)^k}{\cosh r}  |k, k\rangle 
\end{align}
Example (2). Apply $\hat{S}_2(\zeta) $ to the state $|p,0\rangle$:
\begin{equation}
|\Psi_{p,0}\rangle = \hat{S}_2(\zeta) |p, 0\rangle = \frac{1}{{(\cosh r)}^{p+1}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{p+k}{p}^{\frac{1}{2}} (-e^{i\theta} \tanh r)^k |p+k, k\rangle 
\end{equation}
Question:
What is the expression of $|\Psi\rangle$ in Fock basis when apply $\hat{S}_2(\zeta)$ to a general number state $|p, q\rangle$? Specifically, given
\begin{equation}
|\Psi_{p,q}\rangle=\hat{S}_2(\zeta)|p,q\rangle = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty T(m,n)|m,n\rangle,
\end{equation}
what are the coefficients $T(m,n)$? Are there any references that provide a detailed derivation or computation of this state $|\Psi\rangle$?
Any guidance, suggestions, or references on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

The operators $\hat a\hat b\sim K_-$ and $\hat a^\dagger \hat b^\dagger\sim K_+$ are ladder operators of the $su(1,1)$ algebra so one possibility is to use the $SU(1,1)$ disentanglement formula
$$
D(\zeta)=e^{\zeta K_+-\zeta^*K_-}=e^{\eta K_+}e^{-\beta K_0}e^{\gamma K_-}
\tag{1}
$$
where
$$
\zeta= -\frac12 \tau e^{-i\varphi}\, ,\quad \eta=-\tanh\frac\tau 2 e^{-i\varphi}\, ,\quad 
\beta=-2\ln\cosh\frac\tau 2\, ,\quad \gamma=-\eta^*\, .
$$
You can find this in the textbook of

Peremolov, Generalized coherent states,

or more generally by searching for $SU(1,1)$ disentanglement formula.  Another reference would be

A  group-theoretic  approach  to  the  disentanglement  of  generalized squeezing  operators, F.A. Raffaa,  M. Rasettib,  V. Penna, Physics Letters A 438 (2022) 128106

Using  (1) you can work out what you need, although it's probably messy.
An alternative starts by assuming $p>q$ (the case $p<q$ follows a similar reasoning)
and write
$$
\vert p,q\rangle \sim (\hat a\hat b)^q \vert p-q,0\rangle\, . \tag{2}
$$
You can then compute
$$
e^{\zeta K_+-\zeta^*K_-}\vert p,q\rangle
\sim e^{\zeta K_+-\zeta^*K_-}  (\hat a\hat b)^q 
e^{-\zeta K_++\zeta^*K_-} \, e^{\zeta K_+-\zeta^*K_-}\vert p-q,0\rangle\\
 \sim\left( e^{\zeta K_+-\zeta^*K_-}  \hat a\hat b
e^{-\zeta K_++\zeta^*K_-} \right)^q\,\times \, e^{\zeta K_+-\zeta^*K_-}\vert p-q,0\rangle\, .
$$
Since
$$
\left( e^{\zeta K_+-\zeta^*K_-}  \hat a\hat b
e^{-\zeta K_++\zeta^*K_-} \right)\sim 
\left( e^{\zeta K_+-\zeta^*K_-}  K_-
e^{-\zeta K_++\zeta^*K_-} \right)\, ,
$$
you get a closed form in terms of $\zeta$ and hyperbolic functions, which you can then expand (remembering that $K_+$ and $K_-$ do not commute) and apply to $e^{\zeta K_+-\zeta^*K_-}\vert p-q,0\rangle$, which you already know.
Note that I didn't bother to compute factors of $\frac12$ and various square roots of factorials as in Eq.(2); you'll have to figure that out by yourself.

thanks! that's an interesting trick to switch $|p,q\rangle$ to $|p-q,0\rangle$

I think that in case of general $p$, $q$ it may be impossible to obtain simple expressions and relations for $T(m,n,p,q)$. The operator $S_2(\zeta)$ is the exponential of the quadratic boson operator, taking into account the symmetry between $a$ and $b$ it can be written in the following form
$$
S_2(\zeta) = A \exp(\alpha a^\dagger b^\dagger)\exp(\beta(a^\dagger a + b^\dagger b))\exp(\gamma ab)\tag{1}
$$
Such equalities are related to the normal ordering of operators, they are discussed in some books, now I only remember F. Berezin's book on the method of secondary quantization. From (1) it follows
$$
S_2(\zeta)|0,0\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A\alpha^k |k,k\rangle, \quad
S_2(\zeta)|1,0\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^\infty Ae^\beta\alpha^k\sqrt{k+1}\ |k+1,k\rangle.
$$
These formulas are consistent with what is written in the question when
$$
A = \frac1{\cosh(r)}, \quad \alpha = -e^{i\theta}\tanh(r),\quad
e^\beta = \frac1{\cosh(r)}.
$$
Considering $\langle 0,0|S_2(\zeta)$ allows you to find $\gamma=e^{-i\theta}\tanh(r)$. Now, using (1), we can definitely obtain the following formula
$$
S_2(\zeta)|p,q\rangle = \sum_{l = -\mbox{min}(p,q)}^\infty T(p+l,q+l,p,q)|p+l,q+l\rangle
$$
with the coefficients $T$ in explicit form. I think, however, that the expression for the $T$ coefficients will contain a sum for which it is not obvious that it has a simple expression in terms of the binomial coefficients.

Thanks a lot. you are right it is not obvious to have simple recurrence relation for general $|p,q\rangle$
